# i just want to calculate age with the help of DOB

Tags: javascript, json

i am getting DOB from json `var date=data.dob;` by using this `

```
var today = new Date(86400000);
var date=data.dob;          
var timeDiff = Math.abs(today - date);  
rangeOneMin1 = parseInt(timeDiff);
var age1 = Math.ceil(rangeOneMin1 / (1000 * 3600 * 24)) / 365;
```

by applying above code in age1 i'am getting NaN please help please let me know if you want something more

Comment: `data.dob` is in milliseconds?

Comment: from JSON date that i'm getting is like 01/21/2015

Comment: Use date = new Date(data.dob);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey If you want to calculate exact difference with the Years, Month and Days then following will help you:

```
    var today = new Date();
var date = new Date('07/04/1985');

var year=today.getFullYear()-date.getFullYear(); 

var month = today.getMonth() - date.getMonth();
if (month < 0 || (month === 0 && today.getDate() < date.getDate())) {
year--;
month=month+12;     
}

var days = today.getDate() - date.getDate();    

if (days < 0 || (days === 0 && today.getDate() < date.getDate())) {
month--;
days=days+30;       
}

alert(year+"---"+month+"---"+days)
```

You need some more code to calculate days as I have taken 30 days as standard, some month having 31 days or 29 days, so you need to check leap year and 31 days in a month and you will get an exact date difference.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `var today = new Date(86400000);` is not today, but really long time ago. Interpreter don't even bother calculating this date so it is minimum possible date:

```
Fri Jan 02 1970 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

To get today's date object just construct `Date` without parameters. Then you also need to create new `Date` object for `dob` string date.

One more thing, you don't need `parseInt` as difference between two `Date` object will be integer value due to implicit type conversion to number during arithmetic `-` operation.

Finally, you probably want to put `/ 375` under the `Math.ceil` too.

Result will look something like this:

```
var today = new Date();
var date = new Date(data.dob);
var timeDiff = Math.abs(today - date);
var age1 = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24) / 365);
```

Answer (score 2):

Considering the date you get using `var date= data.dob` which is a string in form of `'08/25/1990'`, you can do something like below to get the age

```
var difMS = Date.now() - (new Date(date).getTime()); //Difference in milliseconds from dob to current date
var refDate = new Date(difMS); //Reference date
console.log(Math.abs(refDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970));  //years passed till 1970
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5zpqfLLa/2)

Answer (score 0):

Direct Date Diff is not Allowed in Javascript and hence You are Getting NaN
Instead Use time to get Date Diff and Than convert it to a Year
Please find Below Function for the same

```
function GetAge() {
var one_year=(1000*60*60*24);
var birthDate = new Date(2010,01,01)
var today = new Date();
var todayTime = today.getTime();
var birthDateTime=birthDate.getTime();
var difference_ms = todayTime-birthDateTime;
return Math.round((difference_ms/one_year)/365);
}
```

Comment: var one_year is Actually One_Day.